# ERROR when trying to run program using google map api

Tags: java, netbeans, lambda

I am trying to view a map using google maps api and everything is working except this error which I don't understand how I should solve because I am using netbeans version 8

```
Platform.runLater(() ->
 {mapComponent = new GoogleMapView();
mapComponent.addMapInializedListener(this);
BorderPane root = new BorderPane(mapComponent);
Scene scene = new Scene(root);
panel.setScene(scene);
});
```

The error I got is this one: lambda expression not expected here

lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.6

### (use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)

Answer (score 0):

Your project is set to use Java 6 but you need to configure it to use [Java 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) since [Lambda Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) were introduced in Java 8 and won't work with Java 6.

Comment: I am already using the jdk 8 and I already checked the java platform from properties so can you tell me step by step how I can declare or set it somewhere else because I am already using java8